# How to provide support for custom implementation in a Java library while offering a default implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, autowired

I'm developing a Java-based library that includes a default implementation packaged within the JAR file. However, I also want to provide support for consumer applications to have their own custom implementation if needed.

The default implementation is known by class A, which is part of the library. The consumer application can write their own implementation using class B, as shown in the example below. In class B, there is a `setHandler` method that should override if the consumer application has its own implementation of E. If the consumer does not provide a custom implementation, the default implementation from class A should be used.

**The packaged jar have default implementation A and used in class D**

```
class A implements E{
    // Default implementation of E packed with jar
}

@Configuration
class D {
    
    @Autowired
    E e;
    
    public void config( HttpConfig conf ){

        conf.setHandler(e);
    }

}
```

**The consumer class can have own implementation B which can implements E**

```
class B implements E{
    // Implementation which source repository can have
}
```

How can I design the library to allow the consumer application to easily provide their own implementation for the setHandler method, overriding the default implementation from class E if necessary?

Comment: See [@ConditionalOnMissingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html). Also, prefer constructor injection.

Comment: Could you share example. Should we write conditiononmissing bean on packaged jar ?

Comment: Just a suggestion consumer can override with there custom implementation & use `@Primary` on there implementation for spring to use there custom implementation as primary bean to inject when autowiring, if no custom implementation then your bean should be injected automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. This would be how you would configure it in your library:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
        
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public SomeInterface defaultSomeInterface() {
    return SomeImplementation();
  }

}
```

Then, your consumers can override it by just declaring their own definition of `SomeInterface`.

If I were consuming your library, then I would just do this without the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
        
  @Bean
  public SomeInterface myImplementation() {
    return MyImplementationOfSomeInterface();
  }

}
```

Now, whenever Spring autowires `SomeInterface`, it will use `MyImplementationOfSomeInterface`.

Comment: Thanks . This should work , I will try as you suggested. Is there any design pattern way to solve this problem ?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but this is the recommended way to support bean overriding. This is how Spring does it in all their projects. I'm not aware of any design pattern that could solve this in any kind of elegant way.